# To verify triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis

$ |a+b| \leq |a| + |b | $

for case when $a \geq 0, b <0$ and $a+b \geq 0$

LHS

$a+b = a - (-b) = |a|-|b| \leq |a|+|b| = RHS $

Is this okey ? Thanks

Comment: For that one case, it is okay.  But you are being fairly inefficient if you have to test *six* cases.

Comment: @frejajessen Okay not okey

Comment: If its triangle how can $b \lt 0$

Comment: @abhishekchaudhary No one said that $a$ and $b$ were sides of an actual triangle.  The "triangle" inequality refers to all real numbers.  Not just sides for physical triangles.

Comment: I suppose I should be more encouraging.  Your argument *is* absolutely correct and you really have no reason to doubt yourself.

Comment: @fleablood thanks. i doubt a lot because i am new to this and do not have physical teacher at my disposal. i am watching real analysis course on youtube and learning from book myself. i donot have anyone to discuss my proofs with but stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is OK!

To avoid cases rather square it and remember that $|x|^2=x^2$ and $x\leq |x|$.

You can square it since both sides are nonnegative.

Answer (score 3):

As fleablood and ChristianF say, your analysis of the case $a+b\ge0$ with $a\ge0\gt b$ is okay.

To complete the proof without testing all six cases (by fleablood's count$^*$), you can use the fact(s) that

$$|-(a+b)|=|a+b|=|b+a|\quad\text{and}\quad|-a|+|-b|=|a|+|b|=|b|+|a|$$

to assume, "without loss of generality," that $a+b\ge0$ and $a\ge b$, which leaves only the case $a+b\ge0$ with $a\ge0$ and $b\ge0$ to show, which is trivial, since $|a+b|=a+b=|a|+|b|$ when everything is non-negative. (Doing so turns the problem into an exercise in understanding what it means to say "without loss of generality," or "wlog," as you'll sometimes see it abbreviated.)

$^*$Technically you might say there are *eight* cases to worry about, including $a\ge0$, $b\ge0$, $a+b\lt0$ and $a\lt0$, $b\lt0$, $a+b\ge0$. But these two cases, of course, cannot occur.

Comment: I've seen people and I myself have done four cases (a,b $\ge; < 0$) and that's seems to be noral for me.  In fact I prefer inefficient multiple case testing over difficult to read efficiency.  But I have *never* seen anyone worry about $a+b$ being negative or non-negative.  Eight cases seems excessive.  But not wrong.

Comment: "without loss of generality," can appear a bit hand wavy for a more basic and fundamental level of proof like this.  In my opinion....  Actually I debate this efficiency vs. clarity issue quite a bit.  It comes down to $|a+b| = |a| +|b|$ or whichever of $|a|-|b|, |b|-|a|$ is positive.  Just how obvious is it that ||a|-|b|| < |a| + |b|.  It's obvious $|a|-|b|<|a| +|b|$ and in *another* proof mentally putting absolute value signs up is intuitive.  But as that's what the proof is... it seem obfuscating.

Comment: @fleablood, I agree with everything you say.

Answer (score 0):

In your case $$a\geq 0,b<0,a+b\geq 0$$ we get $$a+b\le a-(-b)=a+b$$

Answer (score 0):

Your case is perfect and okay.

It's worth noting $|a+b|$ equals either $|a|+|b|$ (if $a$ and $b$ are the same sign) or $|a| -|b|$ or $|b|-|a|$ (if $a$ and $b$ are opposite signs).

And obviously $|a|-|b|$ and $|b| -|a|$ are less than    $|a| + |b|$.  (or equal if $a$ or $b$ is $0$)

=====

If $a \ge 0; b\ge 0$ or if $a< 0; b < 0$, or in other words if $a$ and $b$ are in agreement then:

$|a+b| = |\pm|a|  \pm|b|| $ ("$+$" if both $a,b$ are non-negative; "$-$" if both $a,b$ are negative).

$= |\pm(|a| + |b|)| = ||a| + |b| | = |a| + |b|$ (as $|a| + |b| \ge 0$).

If $a,b$ are in disagreement however:

$|a + b| = |\pm |a| \mp |b||=$

$|\pm(|a| - |b|)|=||a|-|b||$.

$= \{|a| -|b|, |b|-|a|\}$ (whichever on is positive).

(for $x\ge 0; y\ge 0$ then $x - y \le x \le x+y$ so)

$\le |a|+ |b|$.

(equal only if $b$ or $a$ equals $0$)